# Build .jar file from Github project

Tags: java, gradle

I want to change code from this [this Github project](https://github.com/Darkside138/DiscordSoundboard). I loaded the project, applied the change and what next?
I tried to run grandlew.bat that created .gradle folder but it is empty. How can I create .jar file?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you run a linux-based operating system, you would typically run

```
$ sh ./gradlew build
```

In your case the call

```
$ sh ./gradlew build
:distTar UP-TO-DATE
:distZip UP-TO-DATE
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:findMainClass
:jar
:bootRepackage
:assemble
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test UP-TO-DATE
:check UP-TO-DATE
:tar
:zip
:build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 35.271 secs
```

You should be able to find the jar in the directory `build/libs/`

```
$ ls -la build/libs/DiscordSoundboard-1.4.11.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 stefan users 86200915 19. Aug 09:09 build/libs/DiscordSoundboard-1.4.11.jar
```

Comment: "compileJava FAILED"

Comment: Then please have a look at the compiler error messages.